# Compare two strings using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am using two strings for a matching program like this:

```
string s1= 5-4-6-+1-+1+1+3000+12+21-+1-+1-+1-+2-3-4-5-+1-+10+1-+1-+;
string s2= 6-+1-+1+1+3000+12+21-+1-+1-+1-+1-+1-+1+1-+1-+;
```

And I am going to write a Regex matching function which compares each part string between each "+" separately and calculates the match percent, which is the number of matches occurring in each string.
For example in this example we have these matches:

```
6

1

1

1

3000

12

21

1

1

1

--

1

--

1

1
```

In this example the match percent is 13*100/15=87%.

Currently I am using the function below, but I think it is not optimized and using Regex may be faster.

```
public double MatchPercent(string s1, string s2) {
    int percent=0;
    User = s1.Split('+').ToArray();
    Policy = s2.Split('+').ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length - 2; i++) {
        int[] U = User[i].Split('-').Where(a => a != "").Select(n => 
                      Convert.ToInt32(n)).Distinct().ToArray();
        int[] P = Policy[i].Split('-').Where(a => a != "").Select(n => 
                      Convert.ToInt32(n)).Distinct().ToArray();
        var Co = U.Intersect(P);
        if (Co.Count() > 0) {
            percent += 1;
        }
    }
    return Math.Round((percent) * 100 / s1.Length );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. In your for loop, you don't use iterator value. So you always should get 98% of match or 0% of match.

Comment: I don't think regular expressions will work. Specifically, I don't think you can maintain state (i.e. the sameness count) over a regex this way. And calculating this after the match would require a variable number of capture groups.

Comment: This function first splits two strings separated by "+" and find match numbers in each part. @KirillBestemyanov I edited the function again, it was my typing mistake.

Comment: Isn't better if you write a math evaluator or something very close to this?

Comment: This is essentially an alignment problem. You need a [suitable sequence alignment algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) here, not regular expressions.

Comment: Konrad's right; instead of making your job easier, switching to a regex solution will make it much more difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: You explained what to do with `+` but I don't understand what the `-` are doing there ? Negative numbers ?

Comment: @HamZa: The '+' characters separate groups. The '-' characters separate individual values within each group. So he's splitting the string into groups, and then finding the intersection of values from each group pair.

Comment: Is there an actual problem that this is supposed to solve?

Comment: First you split both strings into arrays, but next you do not loop using those arrays? Why do you loop through the string instead? Within the loop you create arrays of each array element (probably multivalued features). Within this creation of elements you use a conversion and a distinct. Is that necessairy? Are those values in fixed order? If that is the case, then can you run through each subarray checking if the numbers are equal or not. I would advise you to use the state pattern to implement the method how to evaluate the two different arrays U and P. Later on, you can switch method used.

Comment: @Kamran, So you suppose that you have the same number of groups (divided by '+') on each string? And you want to compare each group in an ordered way: g0 with g'0, g1 with g'1 ...?

Comment: You don't need to do `Split('+').ToArray()`, `Split` returns already an array.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be Levenshtein Word Distance algorithm. Some C# samples:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/05/590814.aspx

From the matching characters you can also calculate the percentages.